# Error: Material-UI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property. A row was provided without id in the rows prop:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Material-UI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property.
A row was provided without id in the rows prop:
```

When I add a new row to my rows in the `DataGrid` component using:

```
const handleNewJobCreation = (newRow) => {
    setRows([
        {...newRow},
        rows
    ]);
}
```

However, I can see that all my rows do have the `id` property inside the dataset, I was wondering how can I fix this issue to be able to get append new data to the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the new `rows` array you are missing spreading the previous array:

```js
const handleNewJobCreation = (newRow) => {
    setRows([
        {...newRow},
        ...rows // <- missing spread operator
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your row objects are missing the `id` property as the error message said. You need to add the `id` prop with a unique value to remove the error. If you have a unique field that does not have the name `id`, you need to add a `getRowId` callback to return the correct id for every row:

```
<DataGrid getRowId={row => row.yourUniqueField}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]